# What can be done about the misuse of [filereader]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I had a look at [filereader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filereader) and it seems to be misused much.

It should be about the [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) File API, but it's used in the wrong context often:

It has 1025 Questions, but if we refine the search and exclude [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) and [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), 587 questions remain. Many of them are tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) (401; 405 questions if [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) and [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) are not excluded).

What can we be done about it? It seems to add relevant information for web developers.

Comment: [html5-filereader] or [javascript-filereader] and [java-filereader]?

Comment: [Here's a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/305493/395862/tags-used-with-filestream-on-so) showing all tags used in conjuntion with "filereader".

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388602/do-i-need-to-close-both-filereader-and-bufferedreader) appears to have had [tag:filereader] for longer than the tag has [actually existed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11471712/revisions), so I'm not too sure what's going on there.

Comment: [Filereader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453225.aspx).  The tag is fine.  Just combine it with some other tag, like [html], to improve the specificity.  You can search on multiple tags.

Comment: There should probably be more specific tags. The Java FileReader class predates HTML5 by many years.